# how to hash password with a basic sign in form in django with mongoengine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, authentication, mongoengine

I'm doing a project with django and mongoengine.
I want to do a basic sign in on my project.
I did a basic form asking for username, password and email.
I thought password hashing was automatic but it isn't, it save what I have wrote.
Here's is my view:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User(username=username, password=password, email=email)
            user.save()
else:
    form = UserForm()
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', locals())
```

Everything is saved but the password is not hash. What have I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [set_password()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) method of the User instance:

```
user = User(username=username, email=email)
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```